# Как прочитать .txt файл из .rar файла

Tags: cmd, текст, rar

Как открыть файл `.txt`, который находится внутри `rar` файла с помощью `cmd`.

Comment: `unrar`, `winrar` ?

Comment: И хочу проста открыть и читать с помощью cmd кода  без unrara. эта нужна мне што бы делать некоторе задачи из MS SQL сервера

Comment: Cmd это рукописный сценарий :) никто вам не мешает вставить в него любой исполняемый код для реализации ваших идей, все в ваших руках! :)

Comment: Но как делать это?) В интернете не смог найти нормальная артикль. Нужна што бы открыть rar файл и читать тот што находится внутри текст филе

Comment: Описание параметров командной строки rar есть и в интернете и в дистрибутиве winrar. Если эти артикли Вам не помогли, значит сначала надо освоить командную строку.

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно указано: в вашем командном сценарии прописывем обращение к unrar с необходимыми ключами и путём к файлу. Либо cd в папку rar-файла, а потом распаковка...